# Triggered Event when showAll() function called

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there any event triggered when the showAll() function is called?
Right now I just found the following events. Also the SHOW Event is not specifically for that.

```
    const AGGREGATE_FIT_TO_VIEW_EVENT = 'aggregateFitToView';
    const AGGREGATE_ISOLATION_CHANGED_EVENT = 'aggregateIsolation';
    const AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT = 'aggregateSelection';
    const ANIMATION_READY_EVENT = 'animationReady';
    const CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT = 'cameraChanged';
    const CAMERA_TRANSITION_COMPLETED = 'cameraTransitionCompleted';
    const CUTPLANES_CHANGE_EVENT = 'cutplanesChanged';
    const CANCEL_LEAFLET_SCREENSHOT = 'cancelLeafletScreenshot';
    const ESCAPE_EVENT = 'escape';
    const EXPLODE_CHANGE_EVENT = 'explodeChanged';
    const EXTENSION_LOADED_EVENT = 'extensionLoaded';
    const EXTENSION_UNLOADED_EVENT = 'extensionUnloaded';
    const FINAL_FRAME_RENDERED_CHANGED_EVENT = 'finalFrameRenderedChanged';
    const FIT_TO_VIEW_EVENT = 'fitToView';
    const FRAGMENTS_LOADED_EVENT = 'fragmentsLoaded';
    const FULLSCREEN_MODE_EVENT = 'fullscreenMode';
    const GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT = 'geometryLoaded';
    const GEOMETRY_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE_EVENT = 'geometryDownloadComplete';
    const HIDE_EVENT = 'hide';
    const HYPERLINK_EVENT = 'hyperlink';
    const ISOLATE_EVENT = 'isolate';
    const LAYER_VISIBILITY_CHANGED_EVENT = 'layerVisibilityChanged';
    const LOAD_GEOMETRY_EVENT = 'loadGeometry';
    const LOAD_MISSING_GEOMETRY = 'loadMissingGeometry';
    const MODEL_ADDED_EVENT = 'modelAdded';
    const MODEL_ROOT_LOADED_EVENT = 'modelRootLoaded';
    const MODEL_REMOVED_EVENT = 'modelRemoved';
    const MODEL_LAYERS_LOADED_EVENT = 'modelLayersLoaded';
    const MODEL_UNLOADED_EVENT = 'modelUnloaded';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We don't have the exact event, but you can get similar result from this [SHOW_EVENT](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/Viewing/#show-event)